# Changing camera position in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, camera, opengl-es-2.0, viewport, orthographic

I'm developing an app for Android devices using OpenGL ES 2.0 and am having trouble understanding how to move my camera - (ultimately, I'm attempting to produce a 'screen shaking' effect - so I need all currently rendered objects to move in unison).

So, at the moment, I have a `SpriteBatch` class which I use to batch up a load of entities and render them all in a single OpenGL call.

Within this class, I have my ***vertex*** and ***fragment*** shaders.

So, I simply create an instance of this class for my objects..... something like:

```
SpriteBatch tileSet1 = new SpriteBatch(100); //100 tiles
```

I'll then render it like this:

```
tileSet1.render();
```

Within my `GLSurfaceView` class (in `onSurfaceChanged`), I am setting up my view like this:

```
//offsetX, offsetY, width and height are all valid and previously declared)

GLES20.glViewport(offsetX, offsetY, width, height); 

Matrix.orthoM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
```

Then, within my `onDrawFrame()` method, I simply call all of my logic and rendering like this:

```
logic();
render();
```

*(Obviously, my game loop has been greatly simplified for the purpose of this question).*

I really am not sure where I'm supposed to put `Matrix.setLookAtM`.

I've tried placing it into my 'GLSufaceView' class - again, in `onSurfaceChanged`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.  How does `setLookAtM` work in relation to the shaders?  I ask because my shaders are in my 'SpriteBatch' class and belong to instances of that class (I could be misunderstanding this completely though).

If any more code is required, please ask and I will post.

Would appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Calls like `Matrix.orthoM()` and `Matrix.setLookAtM()` do not change your OpenGL state at all. They are just utility methods to calculate matrices. They set values in the matrix passed to them as the first argument, and nothing else.

Applying those matrices to your OpenGL rendering is a separate task. The main steps you need for this in a typical use case are:

1. Declare a uniform variable of type `mat4` in your vertex shader.

   ```
   uniform mat4 ProjMat;
   ```
2. Use the matrix while transforming vertices in the vertex shader code:

   ```
   gl_Position = ProjMat * ...;
   ```
3. In your Java code, get the location of the uniform variable after compiling and linking the shader:

   ```
   int projMatLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(progId, "ProjMat");
   ```
4. Calculate the desired matrix, and use it to set the value of the uniform variable:

   ```
   Matrix.orthoM(projMat, ...);
   ...
   GLES20.glUseProgram(progId);
   GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(projMatLoc, 1, false, projMat, 0);
   ```

Note that uniform values have shader program scope. So if you have multiple shader programs that use the matrix, and want to change it for all of them, you'll have to make the `glUniformMatrix4fv()` call for each of them, after making it active with `glUseProgram()`.

Comment: Hi @RetroKoradi, thanks for this.  I am actually doing all you said within my SpriteBatch routine.  So, each instance of an object (as my tileSet1 example above), has all of the code you mentioned.  My confusion is that this is for specific instances of that class (spriteBatch).  What I need to know is how do I move my camera so ***every*** object (or the game world if you will) moves if I don't have any shaders outside of my SpriteBatch class.

Comment: You have a shader program in every `SpriteBatch` instance? Do they actually need different shaders? Otherwise that's very wasteful.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my question, I have a shader pair in every instance of SpriteBatch.  Different batches may require different transformations, so after thinking about it, this was the best way to go - so far, it's not caused any issues (I'm not creating thousands of instances, at most, only about 40) :-)  If they were not in my SpriteBatch class, where would they be best situated?  If I leave them there (as I will, at least for this project), how would I resolve the issue set out in this question? :-) Thanks

Comment: I added a paragraph at the end. Effectively sharing shaders in a scene graph style setup, while still allowing for different shaders where needed, is not entirely trivial. Way beyond the scope of a comment. You'll probably be fine for now with a moderate amount of instances.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can implement something.  Just for future reference, is the 'norm' to have only one shader pair for everything?  Thanks again